# MemoryCache do not update item in Updatecallback

Tags: c#, memorycache

I write the following code (in linqpad) to demonstrate my issue:

```
void Main()
{
    var waitEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    MemoryCache.Default.Set(
        "test", 
        "value", 
        new CacheItemPolicy
        {
            AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)),
            UpdateCallback = (CacheEntryUpdateArguments e) => {
                waitEvent.Set();
                e.Dump();
                e.UpdatedCacheItem = new CacheItem(e.Key, "value2");
            }
        });

    MemoryCache.Default.Get("test").Dump();
    waitEvent.WaitOne();
    waitEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));


    MemoryCache.Default.Get("test").Dump();

}

// Define other methods and classes here
```

The result is as below:

[image]

Can anyone explain why I cannot get "value2" as the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign a new policy also when assigning a new item to `UpdatedCacheItem`. The docs are fairly wishy-washy ([`UpdatedCacheItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheentryupdatearguments.updatedcacheitem(v=vs.110).aspx) seems to say it's required, [`UpdatedCacheItemPolicy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheentryupdatearguments.updatedcacheitempolicy(v=vs.110).aspx) seems to imply it's optional<sup>1</sup>). However, the source makes it clear:

```
// invoke update callback
try {
    CacheEntryUpdateArguments args = new CacheEntryUpdateArguments(cache, reason, entry.Key, null);
    entry.CacheEntryUpdateCallback(args);
    Object expensiveObject = (args.UpdatedCacheItem != null) ? args.UpdatedCacheItem.Value : null;
    CacheItemPolicy policy = args.UpdatedCacheItemPolicy;
    // Dev10 861163 - Only update the "expensive" object if the user returns a new object,
    // a policy with update callback, and the change monitors haven't changed.  (Inserting
    // with change monitors that have already changed will cause recursion.)
    if (expensiveObject != null && IsPolicyValid(policy)) {
          cache.Set(entry.Key, expensiveObject, policy);
    }
    else {
          cache.Remove(entry.Key);
    }
```

`IsPolicyValid` returns `false` if `policy` is `null`.

---

<sup>1</sup>
Quotes:

> you must assign a `CacheItem` object to the `UpdatedCacheItem` property and assign a `CacheItemPolicy` object to the `UpdatedCacheItemPolicy` property

versus:

> you can optionally assign a `CacheItemPolicy` object to the `UpdatedCacheItemPolicy` property

Comment: In fact I try to give a policy but it does not work. But your answer remind me that I can check the source code about the detail, so in the source code, the policy is only valid when 1) there is no change to monitor 2) there is a callback function for new policy.  I have no idea why the item can only updated when there is a callback, if i give a new updatecallback function, the result will be correct. So thanks all the same.